# Deploy only new changes on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, mern

I have deployed a MERN stack application to Heroku. However, when I make new changes to the application, I have to redeploy the whole application. I find this time-consuming and not efficient because I have to wait 2-3 mins for a small change.

Is there any way that I can deploy the latest version of the application, without having to redeploy the whole application.